# Extract PDF metadata using iText Java library

Tags: java, pdf, itext, metadata, itext7

I am trying to get all the XMP metadata stream of a PDF file using the Java library to manipulate PDF files iText. The code I have written is:

```
package iTextExamples;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;

public class ReadMetadata {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String src = "C:\\Path\\PDF123.pdf";
        
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(reader);
        
        System.out.println(doc.getXmpMetadata());
        
        reader.close();
    }

}
```

The result I'm getting is NULL and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unrelated to the issue of getting null, but `doc.getXmpMetadata()` returns a byte array. So you will not be able to print its content with

```java
System.out.println(doc.getXmpMetadata());
```

Instead, you'll have to do something like:

```java
byte[] xmp = doc.getXmpMetadata();
String xmpString = new String(xmp, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(xmpString);
```

About the null issue:

I assume you're trying to get the document level XMP metadata. Make sure that your PDF file actually contains an XMP metadata stream. If not, null is expected.

You can verify with a PDF viewer that is able to show XMP, or with a PDF object viewer. The XMP metadata stream sits in the `Metadata` entry of the documents `Catalog` dictionary:

[image: iText RUPS: metadata entry]